# How to pass Header with underscore in Server Variable IIS URL Rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I'm rewriting my site into diff url and I have to pass header.

So everything is fine. But one header name have with underscore(_).

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="*core*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://xxxxxxx/yyyyy/core{R:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_name" value="name" />
                    <set name="HTTP_address" value="address" />
                    <set name="HTTP_phone_number" value="1234567890" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

All underscore  (phone_number) will convert to Hyphen (phone-number), So the required header is not passed.

I have to pass phone_number

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. I have to pass like HEADER_phone_number .

Please  [refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  for further details.

**HEADER_HeaderName (IIS 5.1 and earlier: This server variable is not available) :**

The value stored in the header . Any header other than those listed in this table must be preceded by "HEADER_" in order for the ServerVariables collection to retrieve its value. This is useful for retrieving custom headers.
Note:
Unlike HTTP_, all characters in HEADER_ are interpreted as-is. For example, if you specify HEADER_MY_HEADER, the server searches for a request header named MY_HEADER.

**HTTP_HeaderName :**

The value stored in the header . Any header other than those listed in this table must be preceded by "HTTP_" in order for the ServerVariables collection to retrieve its value. This is useful for retrieving custom headers.
Note:
The server interprets any underscore (_) characters in  as dashes in the actual header. For example, if you specify HTTP_MY_HEADER, the server searches for a request header named MY-HEADER.